# Failed to run GetFeatureInfo and rendering coverage on the fast path error in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

My layer in geoserver was working fine before 20 days. When I used my system after 20 days for a specific layer Geoserver gave an error : Failed to run GetFeatureInfo on layer [Layer Name]. The layer comes from SQL server.

There are other layers also from the same database store which are rendering well but not this.

I get GetFeatureInfo and rendering coverage on the last path error on the layer.

Error for GetFeatureInfo :

```
2020-04-21 11:22:18,626 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2020-04-21 11:22:18,744 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Failed to run GetFeatureInfo on layer localhost:temp
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetFeatureInfo.execute(GetFeatureInfo.java:88)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetFeatureInfo.run(GetFeatureInfo.java:38)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getFeatureInfo(DefaultWebMapService.java:265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
    at .....
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:132)
    at org.geoserver.wms.featureinfo.VectorRenderingLayerIdentifier.identify(VectorRenderingLayerIdentifier.java:218)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetFeatureInfo.execute(GetFeatureInfo.java:73)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1222)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:353)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1040)
    ... 126 more
```

Error log for Coverage on the last path

```
 21 Apr 15:44:54 INFO [geoserver.security] - Strong cryptography is available
21 Apr 15:45:11 INFO [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
21 Apr 15:45:11 INFO [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getMap
        Angle = 0.0
        BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
        Bbox = SRSEnvelope[7848475.522556748 : 9469551.528779421, 2147145.681351158 : 4677242.27832167]
        BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
        Buffer = 0
        CQLFilter = null
        Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
  GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]],
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0],
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0],
  UNIT["m", 1.0],
  AXIS["Easting", EAST],
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
        Elevation = []
        Env = {}
        Exceptions = SE_XML
        FeatureId = null
        FeatureVersion = null
        Filter = null
        Filters = null
        Format = application/openlayers
        FormatOptions = {}
        Get = true
        Height = 768
        Interpolations = []
        Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@143922a6]
        MaxFeatures = null
        Palette = null
        RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:3857, FORMAT=application/openlayers, BBOX=7848475.522556748,2147145.681351158,9469551.528779421,4677242.27832167, VERSION=1.1.0, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=492, HEIGHT=768, LAYERS=NKBPL:RconGeometry}
        RemoteOwsType = null
        RemoteOwsURL = null
        Request = GetMap
        RequestCharset = UTF-8
        ScaleMethod = null
        Sld = null
        SldBody = null
        SldVersion = null
        SortBy = null
        SortByArrays = null
        SRS = EPSG:3857
        StartIndex = null
        StyleBody = null
        StyleFormat = sld
        Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=Generic]]
        StyleUrl = null
        StyleVersion = null
        Tiled = false
        TilesOrigin = null
        Time = []
        Transparent = false
        ValidateSchema = false
        Version = 1.1.0
        ViewParams = null
        Width = 492
21 Apr 15:45:12 INFO [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
21 Apr 15:45:12 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error rendering coverage on the fast path
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:355)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:269)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:132)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:707)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:287)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:110)
        at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:251)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:55)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:31)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:72)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:52)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:50)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.getMap(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:877)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:264)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1222)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:353)
        ... 131 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1040)
        ... 132 more
INFO: ===============================================================================
INFO: Marlin software rasterizer           = ENABLED
INFO: Version                              = [marlin-0.9.3-Unsafe]
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer                  = org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.useThreadLocal   = true
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.useRef           = soft
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.edges            = 4096
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.pixelWidth       = 4096
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.pixelHeight      = 2176
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.profile          = quality
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.subPixel_log2_X  = 8
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.subPixel_log2_Y  = 3
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.tileSize_log2    = 6
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.tileWidth_log2   = 7
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.blockSize_log2   = 5
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.forceRLE         = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.forceNoRLE       = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.useTileFlags     = true
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.useTileFlags.useHeuristics = true
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.rleMinWidth      = 64
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.useSimplifier    = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.usePathSimplifier= false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.pathSimplifier.pixTol = 0.125
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.clip             = true
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.clip.runtime.enable = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.clip.subdivider  = true
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.clip.subdivider.minLength = 100.0
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.doStats          = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.doMonitors       = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.doChecks         = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.useLogger        = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.logCreateContext = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.logUnsafeMalloc  = false
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.curve_len_err    = 0.01
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.cubic_dec_d2     = 1.0
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.cubic_inc_d1     = 0.2
INFO: sun.java2d.renderer.quad_dec_d2      = 0.5
INFO: Renderer settings:
INFO: CUB_DEC_BND  = 256.0
INFO: CUB_INC_BND  = 51.2
INFO: QUAD_DEC_BND = 128.0
INFO: INITIAL_EDGES_CAPACITY               = 98304
INFO: INITIAL_CROSSING_COUNT               = 1024
INFO: ===============================================================================
```

I tried :

- Delete and add the layer again
- Delete the table and add again
- Tried another version of geoserver
- Delete latest records from table and tried again (All geometries are correct).

WFS is working for the same layer.

Please suggest some pointers to fix this.

Comment: Is the layer queryable

Comment: Does this layr render OK or do you get errors from GetMaps as well? Do the parameters that are inherited from the corresponding GetMap make sense (format, CRS, BBOX…)?

Comment: @nmtoken .. yes the layer is queryable .

Comment: @user30184 .. the layer does not render even by browsing through previewlayers

Comment: I tried adding a new store and add the same layer on a different Geoserver (2.15.2 same version) on a different machine in LAN. this time it rendered .. but not on the current server machine. Currently Database and Geoserver resides on same server machine

Comment: If you have working layers from the same SQL server there must be something special just in this layer and corresponding database table.